# Como asigno roles a usuarios mediante formularios laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream, inertia.js, laravel-permission

Tengo un problema, todo esto en laravel 10, la cual es que necesito que mi aplicación al momento de crear un nuevo usuario en un formulario que yo hice, la cual contiene el rol seleccionado, necesito que ese rol que se seleccionó para el nuevo usuario, actúe como el rol de sistema cuando ingrese en el login y lo redirija al dashboard correspondiente.

mi formulario ya inserta los datos en la tabla users, pero necesito que el rol que se selecciona en el formulario, se le asigne como rol de sistema.

en mi controlador lo tengo así.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    //Obtiene los datos.
    $data = $request->all();

    //encripta la contraseña recibida y crea el usuario
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
    User::create($data);

    //Obtiene el rol seleccionado del formulario
    $role = $request->get('role_id');

    //Asigna el rol al usuario
    $user->assignRole($role);


    //Renderiza al index.
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

lo que tengo en el controlador, es lo único que he probado, pero no logro entender como hacerlo.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tu pregunta. También, aprovechar y [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.. ¿Que es  "rol de sistema"? ¿Que hay en la función `assignRole`? ¿Que es lo que no te funciona?